# How can I convert the format ctx.CurrentItem.Created

Tags: date-time, client-side-rendering, chrome, date-format

I am using SP2013 on-premise. I have applied client side rendering to convert the Item created datetime to specific format.

The problem is "**ctx.CurrentItem.Created**" always return a string format as below

> 2015/10/20 PM 06:09

in my browser. Our farm have Chinese language pack installed and my locale is Hong Kong SAR. It maybe the reason why AM/PM is sitting before the time.

On IE11, when I run JS like below:

```
var d = new Date(ctx.CurrentItem.Created);
```

it works. However it is not supported in Chrome. Chrome cannot handle the "AM/PM" sitting before the time.

My question is, can I change the format of **ctx.CurrentItem.Created** to some ISO format?

Comment: I am working on it, i ll get back to u .

Comment: I am using http://momentjs.com/ to get rid of all those date problems. Saved me lot of time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone suggested the [MomentJS library](http://momentjs.com/), which is great for doing Date calculations and transformations.
But `2015/10/20 PM 06:09` is an invalid Date notation so MomemtJS won't make it valid either.

I would suggest to find the cause why your environment is outputting this invalid notation and fix it at the source.

In the mean time you can change the string with:

```
    var datestring="2015/10/20 PM 06:09";
    var dateparts=datestring.split(' ');//array
    if(dateparts[1].length===2){//am or pm in second array element?
      dateparts.push(dateparts[1]);//move it to the end
      dateparts.splice(1,1);//take out the am/pm in the middle
    }
    var mydate=dateparts.join(' ');//make it one string
    console.log(mydate);
    console.log(new Date(mydate).toString());
    console.log(new Date(mydate).toISOString());
```

Comment: Thanks your solution will work. I am quite sure it is the problem of language pack as we have two farms have identical output. We got various problem on language pack.

Answer (score -1):

Using below code you can get ISO format of SharePoint created field value

```
  string objTime=SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(Convert.ToDateTime("2015/10/20 PM 06:09"));
```

Output:

`2015-10-20T18:09:00Z`

Comment: Nice Server Side Solution! But the question is regarding **CSR**

Answer (score -1):

You should change your String date format

I have tried with `2015/10/20 06:09 PM`

```
var t = new Date("2015/10/20 06:09 PM");
t = t.toISOString()
alert(t);
```

Comment: I don't know how to change the string format returned by ctx.CurrentItem.Created

Comment: ctx.currentItem.Cretaed give you "20/10/2015 06:09 PM" Format. and you have to parse in javascript